# How to size HTML/CSS page so itens does not move when window is resized

Tags: html, css, size

I am having a problem with the positioning of elements on my page.

When I try to open the website on an different computer with an different screen size it gets kind of messy.

That same happens when I resize my window. Certain elements stack in each other. Every element is positioned as absolute.
I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Any fiddle will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Take a look at http://goo.gl/1B1Nhe. This will answer the issue you're encountering.

Comment: different browsers have some default set rules on margins, padding, etc you need to reset them to 0.  https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you code, it is kind of hard. But I'll try to guess the answer.

You probably have set some width, define the total width of your elements and set that a minimum width of the body. Then when the viewports size is smaller, scrollbars will appear.

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some code would be good.
To handle different screen size you might have to make your site responsive. A responsive layout uses percentages instead of pixels for defining layout element sizes. If you are creating a new page you could try BootStrap http://getbootstrap.com/. Bootstrap will make your layout look the same across different screen sizes.